# phpMyAdmin exceeding maximum execution time with basic use

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I'm using EasyPHP for my WAMP server and I seem to have an incredibly slow phpMyAdmin/mySQL database.

Simply trying to add a new table to the database exceeds 30 seconds and times out.

I don't have much in the way of a project to properly test database access, but I do have a user table and am able to retrieve data from that fairly quickly (logging in takes 2-3 seconds which I probably attribute to my PC rather than mySQL).

I appreciate that I could increase the maximum execution time, but 30 seconds to bring up an empty form seems a little overkill and likely means that something's gone awry.

Comment: Which version of EasyPHP and phpMyAdmin are you using?

Comment: Sorry I've only just got back to this, everything seemingly started working fine and I had to press on with the work. I think it was something to do with  xdebug and after disabling it, it now works as expected.